# Change AppEngine DataStore Primary Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm using JPA and for the primary key i have:

```
@Id
private String emailAddress;
```

Is it possible to update primary key emailAddress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported. at all. DataNucleus internals would almost certainly reject such a change.

Answer (score 2):

Although this might be supported it is very dangerous, you better off crating a new kind of entity and replacing your existing objects with it.